# How to query all uses permissions of a Android app in .Net?

Tags: c#, android, .net

Inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I defined a lot of permissions like this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

How can I get a list of the defined permissions with C# inside the `MainActiviy`?

(I want to ask the user to grant all permissions on startup with `RequestPermissions`.)

Comment: I don't think it's possible that way. The permissions are not automatically compiled to code from the AndroidManifest.xml. I think you'll have to request them all separately (or as a list) by specifying them in code. At least that's what I always had to do. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq.  Replace file name with full path of the AndroidManifest.xml

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            var results = doc.Descendants(ns + "uses-permission")
                .Select(x => (string)x.Attributes().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "name").FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: My question was, how I can find out the permissions, from the running App. So I don't have a filename there. So this is not an answer to my quest.

Comment: The code is finding all the strings like "android.permission.INTERNET"